# android-Image View set Tag

Tags: android

I am working on an app in that the Image View uses `imageView.setTag("id"+","+"type")` i.e imageView.setTag(String) .. This is the category id and type of that category so that I perform call to specific URL as per Id and Type on Click of that image....

This id and type are splited with "," and are used separately for further operations depending on the type.

The code is f9 for this scenario... But what when I use Lazy List (Image Loader) for displaying images as requirement,,,, It also uses `set Tag` that creates my problem,,,

How do I manage both conditions.....

```
Is any other alternative than set Tag for either of the purposes....
```

Thank You,,,

With Regards,

Arpit

Comment: "I am working on an app in that the Image View uses imageView.setTag("id","type")" -- no, you do not, as that will not compile.

Comment: it's like  String string="id"+","+"type" ; imageView.setTag(string); and code is working for that

Answer (score 2):

There are two version of setTag one which takes object as an argument and other takes key and object as an argument here is [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29).
Hope this help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class to save your View object's states.

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvPost;
    int id;
    String type;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = myContext.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.postitem, null);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.tvPost = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.postTitleLabel);
        vh.id=? (Set your ID)
        vh.type= ? (Set your type)
        convertView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
}
```