# Android - Add multiple tags to ImageView

Tags: android, tags, imageview

I am new at android programming and want to create an application in which I can add multiple custom tags to an displayed Image. I researched a bit and found out about`setTag()` method of ImageView. But it does mention if it allows multiple tagging.
Also is there any way that those tags to remain visible (along with appropriate tagged position) on the image?

Will I require an SurfaceView or GridView for this?

Sources :

[Android Image View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)

[android-Image View set Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6634631/1833437)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of looking for multiple tags you can use a class MyTag as follows to tag more than one data to a view

```
public class MyTag
{
   int  int_Tag;
   String  string_Tag;
   MyClass  myclass_obj_Tag;


    public MyTag()
    {
      int_Tag=0;
      string_Tag=null;
      myclass_obj_Tag=null;
    }

    public MyTag(int i,String s,MyClass m)
    {
      int_Tag=i;
      string_Tag=s;
      myclass_obj_Tag=m;
    }


}
```

create an object of this class and assign values to variables in object

```
MyTag myTag=new MyTag(1,"string_tag",myClass_obj);
iv.setTag(myTag);
```

just give it a try,I have used this method,

Answer (score 0):

You can add any object as a tag. If the data you're adding need more data, the simplest way  would be to add a Hashtable  as the tag. Then add all the key/value pairs you want to that Hashtable.