# Asking for name of image in if statement

Tags: java, android

My Question is, how to ask in if statement for the name of an image in a ImageView. I have tried it with image.equals("imageName") but it doesn't work.
I will display Random images my Code looks like:

```
Random rand = new Random();
String str = "img_" + rand.nextInt(3);
```

In the if statement I have tried this:

```
if (str.equals("img_" + 1)){...}
```

And my ImageView, wich shows a Random image (this works fine) looks like this:

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable", getApplicationContext())));
```

I think, i have to handle with "image" and not "str" but i don't know how???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expected to happen by comparing an ImageView to a String. Those are not the same type, so equalling them won't work.

If you'd like to associate the ImageView with some object, then you can use tags.

```
Random rand = new Random();
String str = "img_" + rand.nextInt(3);
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
image.setTag(str);
int resId = getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable", getApplicationContext()));
image.setImageDrawable(resId);
```

And check it later

```
String tag = (String) image.getTag();
if (tag.equals("img_1")){...}
```

Comment: I have just one ImageView, wich changes its image randomly. The Images are named (img_0, img_1, img_2, img_3). How can i set tags for all images with just one ImageView?

Comment: The tag is for the ImageView, and you can only have one. To reset it, you just call setTag again. By image do you mean drawable? The resource id string that you are using is the "label" for those

Comment: Yes I mean drawable images

Comment: Okay, same problem, then, an ImageView can only show one image at a time. If you'd like a new random image, then just call setImageDrawable again after recreating the random string

Answer (score 1):

You can set the tag for each image and then check that image by tag like this

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageview1" 
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:tag="tag_image1"/>
```

and get image tag name like

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewbyId(R.id.imageview1);

String strImageTagName= (String) imageView.getTag();
```

and then check via IF condition

```
if(strImageTagName.equals("tag_image1"))
{ 
      // do something
}
else
{
     // do something
}
```

Comment: But I have used just one ImageView, is it possible to have more than one tags on just one ImageView?

Comment: i think this way you can do it, assign multiple tags to one view ,follow this link , may be this will help you ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533229/android-add-multiple-tags-to-imageview